# JAXB generated objects to business/domain objects

Tags: java, jaxb, mapping, dozer, apache-commons-beanutils

Which library to choose for mapping JAXB generated objects to business/domain objects? I'm just thinking between Dozer, Apache Commons BeanUtils, Spring BeanUtils. I read that Dozer has some performance issues. Is that true? Is there anything better than those three?

I'll mention that there will be something a little more than 100 JAXB classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used Orika, Smooks and dozer.

Orika: is very intuitive, but the development is programmatic.

Dozer: uses the xml mappings, but is able to avoid them if the source and the target are equal.

Smooks: i do not recommend it, the mapping files are too complex.

Comment: What do you mean by "programmatic" for Orika?

Comment: Dozer and Smooks has a XML to map the entities, instead Orika uses Java classes to map each other. [example](http://code.google.com/p/orika/wiki/GettingStartedGuide)

Comment: Maybe it's better that is not XML based because of easier refactoring by IDE tool!? I'm guessing that your option is Dozer?

Comment: I prefer dozer because if the source bean and target bean have the same structure didn't needed of configurations.

Comment: in Orika too, if there is no configuration you can just map objects without register them :)

Answer (score 2):

Transmorph: Transmorph is a free java library used to convert a Java object of one type into an object of another type (with another signature, possibly parameterized).

EZMorph: EZMorph is simple java library for transforming an Object to another Object. It supports transformations for primitives and Objects, for multidimensional arrays and transformations with DynaBeans

Commons-BeanUtils: ConvertUtils -> Utility methods for converting String scalar values to objects of the specified Class, String arrays to arrays of the specified Class.

Commons-Lang: ArrayUtils -> Operations on arrays, primitive arrays (like int[]) and primitive wrapper arrays (like Integer[]).

Commons-Convert: Commons-Convert aims to provide a single library dedicated to the task of converting an object of one type to another. The first stage will focus on Object to String and String to Object conversions.

Morph: Morph is a Java framework that eases the internal interoperability of an application. As information flows through an application, it undergoes multiple transformations. Morph provides a standard way to implement these transformations.

Lorentz: Lorentz is a generic object-to-object conversion framework. It provides a simple API to convert a Java objects of one type into an object of another type. (seems dead)

Spring framework: Spring has an excellent support for PropertyEditors, that can also be used to transform Objects to/from Strings.

Dozer: Dozer is a powerful, yet simple Java Bean to Java Bean mapper that recursively copies data from one object to another. Typically, these Java Beans will be of different complex types.

ModelMapper: ModelMapper is an intelligent object mapping framework that automatically maps objects to each other. It uses a convention based approach to map objects while providing a simple refactoring safe API for handling specific use cases.

OTOM: With OTOM, you can copy any data from any object to any other object. The possibilities are endless. Welcome to "Autumn".

Smooks: The Smooks JavaBean Cartridge allows you to create and populate Java objects from your message data (i.e. bind data to) (suggested by superfilin in comments).

Transmorph (pretty recent), EZMorph, Dozer, ModelMapper, OTOM are all serious candidates. Dozer seems to be the most active project though (and maybe the most advanced).

Orika is a Java Bean mapping framework that recursively copies (among other capabilities) data from one object to another. It can be very useful when developing multi-layered applications.